# Understanding SLOCCount output

Tags: python

I recently run the [SLOCCount](http://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/) tool because I needed to estimate the number of lines in a large project.

This is what it showed:

```
Totals grouped by language (dominant language first):
python:        7826 (100.00%)

Total Physical Source Lines of Code (SLOC)                = 7,826
Development Effort Estimate, Person-Years (Person-Months) = 1.73 (20.82)
 (Basic COCOMO model, Person-Months = 2.4 * (KSLOC**1.05))
Schedule Estimate, Years (Months)                         = 0.66 (7.92)
 (Basic COCOMO model, Months = 2.5 * (person-months**0.38))
Estimated Average Number of Developers (Effort/Schedule)  = 2.63
Total Estimated Cost to Develop                           = $ 234,346
 (average salary = $56,286/year, overhead = 2.40).
```

I'm not entirely sure how it comes up with all those estimates but one in particular threw me off, the `Development Effort Estimate`. I read about the [COCOMO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COCOMO) model but I'm still a bit lost.

What is the meaning of this estimate in simple words?

Comment: It's a measure (estimate) of how much time it took to create the 7.8k lines of Python code.  If you believe in divisible man-months of effort, it would have taken one person about 21 months to produce, or two people about 11 months, or three people about 7 months.  In practice, it doesn't scale linearly like that — and some tasks are indivisible.  Putting 9 women to work to produce a baby in 1 month doesn't work.  And is $56k really the average salary for a programmer these days?

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler, you should put that cmmt as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Development Effort Estimate* is a measure of how much time it might have taken to create the 7.8k lines of Python code.

If you believe in divisible [man-months](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201835959) of effort, it would have taken one person about 21 months to produce (might be about right), or two people about 11 months (a bit optimistic), or three people about 7 months (quite optimistic). In practice, it doesn't scale linearly like that — and some tasks are indivisible. Putting 9 women to work to produce a baby in 1 month doesn't work, even though it takes 1 woman 9 months to produce a baby.

Is $56k really the average salary for a programmer these days?

Comment: While both points are absolutely true, 1) you can adjust both salary and overhead to whatever values seem appropriate with with your particular job market and taxes/expenses estimates; 2) schedule/effort estimates are not exactly linear, they have an exponential component which too can be adjusted.Both facts are probably obvious, and neither is super-helpful but they do help a little bit, especially if you have real man-hours and expenses data to calibrate algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

COCOMO calculates how long it takes the average developer in a large company to create this software. 
It's a very rough estimate, but there are parameters (called drivers) that you can tweak to make it more accurate to your case.

Some tools like ProjectCodeMeter can auto-detect these parameters and make the calculation for you.